# PHP Проблема с кодировкой

Tags: php

API работает во всех браузерах нормально, кроме IE 11.
Есть метод, который принимает данные через `$_REQUEST`.

В хроме отправляется:`?action=getHouseInfoByAddress&address=%D0%B3%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0,%20%D1%83%D0%BB%20%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F,%20%D0%B4%2012`.

В IE отправляется: `?action=getHouseInfoByAddress&address=Ð³ ÐÐ¾ÑÐºÐ²Ð°, ÑÐ» ÐÐ¾ÐºÑÐ¾Ð²ÑÐºÐ°Ñ, Ð´ 12`.

Из-за кодировки не отрабатывает API. Пытаюсь декодировать, но проблема в том, что с IE запрос приходит в ISO-8859-1, а `mb_detect_encoding` говорит, что это "UTF-8". Есть решение?

Comment: iconv() и для определения в яндексе найди декодер лебедева, и вставь строки

Comment: Надо браузеру через заголовки сказать, в какой кодировке ему работать. Иначе, он будет слать в той кодировке, в какой ему больше нравится.